# My react child callback returns the previous data (navbar)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, nav

I am learning React and I have a problem with my childCallback, for return data from child to parent.

I make a navbar and when I click on the navButton, the parent receive the name of the precedent button, I have to click two times for display the good data.

Here is my code :

```
//PARENT COMPONENT
export const Profil = () => {
  const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState("infos");

  const handleCallback = (childData, e) => {
    setNavActive(childData);
  };

  // View
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar callback={handleCallback} />
      <Infos />
      <Gpg />
      {navActive}
    </div>
  );
};

//CHILD COMPONENT 
export const Navbar = ({ callback }) => {
  // Nav Items
  let nav = [
    { key: 1, name: "infos" },
    { key: 2, name: "gpg" },
    { key: 3, name: "compte" },
    { key: 4, name: "otp" },
    { key: 5, name: "journal" },
  ];

  // State
  const [activeTitle, setActiveTitle] = useState(nav[0].name);

  // Change the selected nav
  function selectNav(e) {
    let selected = e.target.innerText;
    setActiveTitle(selected);
  }

  const onTrigger = () => {
    callback(activeTitle);
  };

  // View
  return (
    <Nav tabs>
      {nav.map((item) => (
        <NavItem key={item.key} onClick={onTrigger}>
          <NavLink
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={selectNav}
            active={activeTitle === item.name}
          >
            {item.name}
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      ))}
    </Nav>
  );
};
```

I don't know how to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove onclick from NavItem and call your callback function from selectNav function directly.

Comment: Same problem, thanks for the optimisation though

Comment: Add useEffect hook in parent component and pass navActive as its dependency, because when you pass a value to parent component it should be re-rendered after updating the value. And also put some console.log() in each function so you will get to know the flow of data.

Comment: like this ? ```useEffect(() => {}, [navActive]);```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the `setActiveTitle(selected)` in Navbar, with console.log I test and the value is good before this.

Comment: Ok I found : ```function selectNav(e) {
    let selected = e.target.textContent;
    setActiveTitle(selected);
    callback(selected);
  }```